# how should I define these creatures in subclasses?

Tags: java, inheritance, enums

I have a super class defined like this:

```
public class Creature {

    Terrain terrain;

    //symbols on cards
    boolean flyingCreature;
    boolean magicCreature;
    boolean canCharge;
    boolean rangedCombat;
    public int specialAbility = 0;

    public Creature(Terrain startTerrain, boolean flying, boolean magic, boolean charge, boolean ranged, int special){
        terrain = startTerrain;
        flyingCreature = flying;
        magicCreature = magic;
        canCharge = charge;
        rangedCombat = ranged;
        specialAbility = special;
    }
}
```

And I have subclasses defined like this:

```
public class MountainCreature extends Creature{
    public enum Creature{
        GOBLINS, DWARVES, TROLL, GREATEAGLE, BROWNDRAGON,
        MOUNTAINMEN, GIANTROC, GIANTCONDOR, CYCLOPS, GREATHAWK,
        OGRE, BROWNKNIGHT, LITTLEROC, GIANT, MOUNTAINLION
    }

    public MountainCreature(int startTerrain, boolean flying, boolean magic, boolean charge, boolean ranged, int special){
        super(startTerrain, flying, magic, charge, ranged, special);
    }
}
```

I have 15 different MountainCreatures (they are the ones in my enum), and they each have variations of all of the characteristics in my constructor.  How can I define each of my Creatures separately?  Should I not use an enum here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to accomplish.  Do you want 15 different objects?  Or 15 different "kinds" of `MountainCreature`, where you can instantiate many objects of each different kind?  Perhaps post some sample code that would use `MountainCreature` so that we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: What I would expect is that using an enum will end up creating problems for you.  You will begin using if or switch statements in order to make choices in behavior for the different types of creatures.  I would investigate having the various kinds of creatures as objects derived from the Creature class.  This would be the straightforward object oriented approach.

Comment: In any case, if you do define an `enum`, don't call it `Creature`.  Now you have the name `Creature` with two different meanings, which will probably just lead to confusion or other errors.

Comment: @RichardChambers generally correct.  But if you have a lot of different types, and the behaviors aren't all that different (especially if the only difference is in some numeric constants, like maybe the different creature types have different heights or strength measurements or something), then defining a type for each one can be too heavy a solution.

Comment: I have 7 different 'kinds' of creatures, so mountain, swamp, desert etc.  and then in the mountains there are goblins, dwarves, trolls, etc, in the desert there are sandworms, nomads, vultures etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the `MountainCreature` constructor `protected`, so it can't be instantiated directly, but subclasses are still possible in the future.

If all creatures have the same attributes, then in this suggestion you wouldn't need the enum.  You could create a `public static` method for each creature to be created, e.g.

```
public static MountainCreature createGoblin() {
    return new MountainCreature( /* goblin-specific characteristics here */);
}

public static MountainCreature createDwarf() {
    return new MountainCreature( /* dwarf-specific characteristics here */);
}

// And so on...
```

Alternatively, you could keep the enum and make a factory method that takes the enum value and decides which creature to create:

```
public static MountainCreature createCreature(MountainCreature.Creature type) {
    MountainCreature creature;
    switch(type) {
        case GOBLINS:
            creature = new MountainCreature( /* goblin-specific characteristics here */);
        break;
        case DWARVES:
            creature = new MountainCreature( /* dwarf-specific characteristics here */);
        break;
        // And so on...
    }
    return creature;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define classes for each one of your creatures if the only thing they have in common is the Creature's properties.

But if for example, the goblins and the ogre can live under a bridge or in a cave you can use a class called HideCreature wich extends Creature and then define a Class Goblin wich extends HideCreature and another Class Ogre wich also extends HideCreature.

That's the herence concept. Search for common ground then combine.